# Open page in new tab using the HyperLink ?

Tags: html, asp.net, hyperlink

I am trying to open the new page in the new tab after clicking on the web link, I am using the `asp:hyperlink` the hyperlink `navigate url` is getting bind in the grid but when I tried to run it throws `Server tag not formed`. I have tried using `linkbutton` also but could not able to open the link into new tab here is my hyperlink code .

```
  <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ViewTask.aspx?TaskID={0}",Helper.GetEncryptedData((Eval('ID').ToString()))) %>' Target="_blank" runat="server" >View</asp:HyperLink>
```

I have tried using the `anchor tag`,`Link Button` and `Hyperlink` button nothing works.
With anchor tag it opens the link in the new tab but the url is encrypted which gives messed up querystring values on code behind of redirected page with `HTML encoded` values in query string.
With `LinkButton` i was able to get the write querystring values but not able to open it in the new tab.
And with `Hyperlink` it gives above mentioned error.Any help would be great.

Comment: That is not possible since not all browser support tabs, and there is no way to force to open a tab. This is just a user setting in his/her browser.

Comment: @PatrickHofman That's not entirely correct. There's no way to ensure that a link will open in a new tab, but as long as the `Target` is set to `_blank` then the vast majority of the time it will open in a new tab. Users have to actively go into their browser settings to switch it to open in a new window instead of tab. Either way, the user will get their desired behavior.

Comment: But OP has this already in code and asks how to force it. There is no way to force it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Eval('ID')` should be `Eval("ID")`

```
<asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("ViewTask.aspx?TaskID={0}",Helper.GetEncryptedData((Eval("ID").ToString()))) %>' Target="_blank" runat="server" >View</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Stupid of me didn't get that. Thanks again.

Comment: i wanted to but stacks policy not mark answer under 15 min not allowing me too. Marked now !